# Join multiple flv with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, red5

i am trying to join two flv files using -concat option in ffmpeg-1.1 . I have created a list named mylist.txt and placed two flv files into it, but the problem i am facing is that the output of first file in mylist.txt streams perfect but video breaks into pieces when it comes to the second file. Looks like i am using the wrong options with -concat, please guide me for suitable commands with -concat option. Following are the commands and configurations i am using for transcoding .flv files:-

mylist.txt

file '/root/1.flv'
file '/root/2.flv'

ffmpeg command :-

ffmpeg -re -f concat -i /root/mylist.txt -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.flv

Following link is the output of ffmpeg command :-
http://pastebin.com/P3uaUDEd

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your ffmpeg command. Then highlight your text and press Ctrl+k to format it correctly.

Comment: Edited my post with link for the output.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the 2 files were encoded the same (and even if they were it could still be a problem) you would need to transcode the audio and video so that things like time stamps, bitrates, resolutions and other codec internals are correct in both streams.  Change you `acodec copy` and `vcodec copy` to the codecs of your choice (x264 and mp3/aac are good choices).